# Entering a text in a dialog form

Tags: java, android, dialog

What I want to do is quite simple : to display a dialog form containing an `EditText` in which the user can specify a message.

So far, I have tried to use the `DialogFragment`class. With the explanations found in the developer's guide, I have been able to display an alert dialog box showing a message. But I can't figure out how neither to change the layout of the `AlertDialog` created to use an XML file of my own or to replace the `AlertDialog` with a customized class extending the `View` class for instance.

Am I missing something? Or am I completely on the wrong way?

Thanks in advance for the time you will spend trying to help me.

Comment: Hi you want to create EditText in DialogBox ha?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You absolutely can do this, even using an `AlertDialog`!

You just have to set a custom layout for the dialog, in `AlertDialog` you would use the `setView` method and if you want to use a more generic dialog you can use the `setContentView` method.

You can take a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog for some more information and an example.

The example in the link provided is contrived without question but it is meant as a stepping stone towards a goal similar to what you are trying to accomplish.

There is a similar [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318013/create-custom-dialog/5318178#5318178) that might be of use to you.